# How to find the surface area of the n-1 sphere?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, surface-integrals

**Q:** Pick n>0 and suppose that Vol_n is the volume of the n-ball B(**0**,1), find the surface area of the n-1 sphere ∂B(**ξ**,ρ)?

I am totally stucked at where to start this problem. I have tried the transformation formula and the formula for finding surface areas itself. But neither of them seems to be related to the volume of the hypersphere. Need a hand! Thank you!

For more of you looking for answers for this problem, the link below is also useful..

https://www.quora.com/Geometry-Why-is-the-surface-area-of-a-sphere-the-derivative-of-the-volume-of-the-sphere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Increasing $\rho$ by a little bit, results in a change in volume which is proportional to the surface area (this is another way of saying that the derivative of the volume is the surface area)

Check that when $n=2,3$ , the familiar formulas do obey this rule: $\frac d{dr}(\pi r^2)=2\pi r$ and $\frac d{dr}...
(\frac43\pi r^3)=4\pi r^2$.

So, we get

> $\partial B(\xi,\rho)=\frac d{d\rho} (\operatorname {Vol_n} \rho^n)=n\cdot \operatorname {Vol_n}\cdot \rho^{n-1}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how could you see that the change in volume is proportional to the surface area, and how could you realise that it is the derivative relationship?..

Comment: Good question.   It's actually only true for "infinitesimal" changes...  Here's a link:  http://www.askamathematician.com/2013/02/q-is-it-a-coincidence-that-a-circles-circumference-is-the-derivative-of-its-area-as-well-as-the-volume-of-a-sphere-being-the-antiderivative-of-its-surface-area-what-is-the-explanation-for-this/

Comment: For my part, it's evidently true in lower dimensions...  and this behavior  generalizes...  check out the link to higher dimensions in the link above.

Comment: Cool that makes sense thanks heaps!